# Sending data to ChartJsLineChart in ChartJs.Blazor

Tags: chart.js, blazor

I am using ChartJsLineChart in ChartJs.Blazor nuget, and I am stuck at sending data to ChartJsLineChart.

All the examples including this one

http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4363/Adding-Charts-To-Server-Side-Blazor-Using-ChartJs-Blazor.aspx

uses TimeTuple as a way to add data to dataset

```
_WeightDataSet = new LineDataset<TimeTuple<int>>
        {
            BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(System.Drawing.Color.White),
            BorderColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red),
            Label = "Weight per Day",
            Fill = false,
            BorderWidth = 2,
            PointRadius = 2,
            PointBorderWidth = 2,
            SteppedLine = SteppedLine.False,
            Hidden = false
        };
```

I am wondering what would be an alternative to TimeTuple. I tried using Tuple but that resulted with a blank chart ie. no YValues where not recognized.

Comment: Hey, I'm the maintainer of the library you're using. If you're still facing this issue, I'd suggest trying with the new [2.0 version](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor/releases/tag/v2.0.0) and opening a new issue on https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor if you don't manage to get it working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any reference type supported by ChartJs.Blazor to add data to the chart. I identified 3 main categories of types of data that are used with line charts.
1) If you simply want to use a (double/int) value type along both x-axis and y-axis then you can use the ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Point data type. For e.g.

```
_WeightDataSet = new LineDataset<ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Point>
        {
            BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(System.Drawing.Color.White),
            BorderColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red),
            Label = "Weight per Day",
            Fill = false,
            BorderWidth = 2,
            PointRadius = 2,
            PointBorderWidth = 2,
            SteppedLine = SteppedLine.False,
            Hidden = false
        };
```

You might also have to configure the xAxes in the config to a LinearCartesianAxis object for this to work.
2) If you want the x-axis to have a time value whereas the y-axis to have a double value then you need to use TimeTuple as mentioned in the example quoted by you. You might also have to configure the xAxes object in the config to be a TimeAxis object.
3) If you want double (or int) value to be plotted along y-axis against string labels on the x-axis then you need to use Wrappers provided in the ChartJs.Blazor.ChartJS.Common.Wrappers namespace and configure the xAxes to a CategoryAxis object in the config. An example of this is provided in the code hosted on https://github.com/LearnC0de/BlazorAppLineChart/blob/master/BlazorAppLineChart/BlazorAppLineChart/Pages/LineChart.razor

Comment: Answers that contains only links will be delete in future so please post your answers with code and its explanation.

Comment: Luckily, datasets can now use any type and don't require the wrappers anymore. This was fixed in [version 2.0](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor/releases/tag/v2.0.0).